# How to set the ringing duration in Skype before it automatically rejects a call?

Tags: skype

When calling someone Skype is ringing for 30 seconds or more (might be even 1 minute, I didn't look at the clock) until it's auto-rejected if the other user doesn't accept/reject the call.

However, when I am called the incoming call is rejected after a few (10-15) seconds which is very annoying. Is there some hidden option to set the ringing duration?

Some facts which may or may not be important:

- Skype 4.1 - don't suggest upgrading to Skype 5, it's a piece of crap.
- I'm signed in to Skype from two locations (office PC and home PC - both have the same Skype version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find this at the following:

> Tools > Options > Calls > Voicemail

There is a section labelled, "Send calls to voicemail if..."

Set the time incoming calls have before being redirected to voicemail:

> I do not answer within [time] seconds

Comment: I'm not using voicemail at all. However, I just enabled the "forward calls" checkbox so I could change the duration and then unchecked it again. I'll test it asap and accept your answer if it fixed it.

Comment: Oops, completely forgot about that answer - +1 and accepted since it did fix the problem. Pretty retarded that this option is apparently honored even if "forward calls" is disabled.

Comment: Note that now from Skype in 2022 (Windows Skype version 8.88.0 and Application Version 15.88.3401, probably similar across other systems?) it's press the "..." menu pullout, then settings, Account & Profile, Your Account, which opens their website in a browser... then down the page under Manage Features click Call Forwarding & voicemail, and you'll have the option of "Forward calls if I don't answer"... mine was set to 1 second... led to a lot of frustrated people!